# PHP Trouble replacing string containing dash and underscore

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have tried, read and searched to to avail.
I just need to replace `-m_` with `-b_` in a string containing an image name / location.

For instance:
I just want to replace;

*some-image-name-hyphenated-m_15235101.jpg*

with

*some-image-name-hyphenated-b_15235101.jpg*

Easy right?

```
$mediumimage = 'some-image-name-hyphenated-b_15235101.jpg';
```

I tried

```
$biggerimage = preg_replace("-m_", "-b_", $mediumimage);
```

and

```
$biggerimage = preg_replace('-m_', '-b_', $mediumimage);
```

Also backslashing along with other tries resulting from searches.

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '-' found
```

I don't feel well right now...

I beseech anyone who is smarter than me e.g..... any one here.

Comment: The warning tells something is wrong with the arguments you pass to the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function. Take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `$biggerimage = str_replace("-b_", "-m_", $mediumimage);`

Comment: THANK YOU... Guess I was too close to see! Thank you again....

Comment: You are welcome :)